# Android BLE characteristics getValue is no any response?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to configure READ characteristic with notification attribute. At the moment I can see this characteristic on android app with properties READ and NOTIFY.

here is my device's uuid info :

[UUID info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4PR4.png)

YES, I need to notification attribute first , then second I send command , that will be receive value, but ,
in fact , I don't receive any value , I don't even know what's wrong, here is my code :

```
     public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status){

          if (status == gatt.GATT_SUCCESS){ 

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                  public void run() {
                      BluetoothGattService gattService = gatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID);

                      if(gattService != null){
                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic = gattService.getCharacteristic(NOTIF_UUID);
                        if (gattCharacteristic != null ){
                           for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor : gattCharacteristic.getDescriptors()){
                              descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                              boolean sucess = gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                           }
                        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);  

                       }
                characteristic = gattService.getCharacteristic(WRITE_DATA); 
                if (characteristic != null){
                   sendCommand(characteristic, gatt); //send command
                }     
                    
now , I have already send command , and it's return success , because onCharacteristicWrite() has response,
but onCharacteristicRead() and onCharacteristicChanged() is not any response? Why ?

which part I missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
```

instead of

```
  descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
```